# Как называется/реализовать sroll эффект?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода, прокрутка

На сайте есть `header`, внутри которого есть `list` с якорями на секции. Необходимо менять их состояние (цвет текста, ну или что - то другое), при достижении секции блоком `header`.

Мой старый пример для наглядности, но он очень как по мне плохой. Так как будет отслеживаться событие `scroll`, то нужно по идеи предотвратить холостые вызовы функции по типу: когда `header` достигает нужную секцию, то он `list__item` задает `class`, но он это будет делать на протяжении всего расстояния, пока не достигнет другой секции. Такое поведение надо предотвратить.

```js
 $(document).on('scroll', function() {
  $('.menu__link').each(function() {
   var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
   if ( $(document).scrollTop() >= $(anchor).offset().top - $('.header').outerHeight()) {
    $('.menu__link').removeClass('current');
    $(this).filter('[href="'+ anchor +'"]').addClass('current');
   } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight() >= 
    $('.footer').offset().top ) {
     $('.menu__link').removeClass('current');
     $(this).filter('[href="'+ anchor +'"]').addClass('current');
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
p,
figure,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
dl,
li,
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  font-style: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.menu__link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.current {
  color: #784;
}

section {
  height: 800px;
}

#first {
  background: #641;
}

#second {
  background: #453;
}

#third {
  background: #834;
}

.footer {
  height: 600px;
  background: #761;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Scroll</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="page">
  <header class="header">
    <menu class="menu header__menu">
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#first" class="menu__link current">First</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#second" class="menu__link">Second</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#third" class="menu__link">Third</a>
      </li>
    </menu>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <section id="first"></section>
    <section id="second"></section>
    <section id="third"></section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вызов `.addClass` с уже добавленным классом никакого вреда нe приносит. Но если Вам это важно - проверяйте `.hasClass`.

Comment: @Igor, это был пример. допустим в этом условие, по мимо изменении класса, может быть еще какое либо действие. То что нужно проверку, это понятно, но нужно вначале придумать как написать функцию максимально эффективно для этой задачи.